# Highlight cell between certain date

Tags: excel, date, conditional-formatting

I want to highlight the cell in excel sheet that are in between certain defined date. How to do it using conditional formatting?

I have selected the row that needs to be filtered and used conditional formatting, new rule and select "format only cells that contains" and entered date between Lets say Fri 7/12/2013 to Fri 7/19 and format it with one of the color.

This option worked and highlighted some of the cells but the problem is that it highlights that week dates but some other dates as well like Fri 8/16/2013

Comment: Does the cell you want to format contain `DDD m/d/yyyy`? or is it split between two cells, as in `DDD` and `m/d/yyyy`?

Comment: @MattHead93  The cells that I want to highlight are in general format. But they are written manually in m/d/yyyy format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to conditional format the dates (in American format, from UK system) as follows;

First, I ensured that the dates are formatted as yours.
[image]

Then, I opened up the conditional formatting rule, and **left out the =** - note, here I had to input the UK format dates, you should be able to use your local format.
[image]

Pressing `OK`, and then clicking back into the rule, it shows that leaving out the = has turned the date into a `dateserial`.
[image]

Which then gives me the final product...

[image]

Let me know if you have any problems, or questions!

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Its working now. Actually the problem was in date format. As I changed the date format, conditional formatting worked.

Comment: @user2572271 No problem - so was the problem rectified from this answer? If so, please "select as answer" by clicking the tick just below the down arrow :)